# Checking if Outlook mail item is active

Tags: vba, outlook

The following code is the code for sending Outlook mail:

```
Sub SendEmail()

Dim OutlookApp As Object
Dim MItem As Object

Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim Sendrng As Range
Set Sendrng = Worksheets("Test").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Sendrng.Copy

Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
With MItem
    .To = "test@email.com"
    .Subject = "Test"
    .Display
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
End With

End Sub
```

How can I check if the Outlook mail item is active?

I am looking for a code like this:

```
.Display
Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
If MItem is not active then 
    exit sub
End if
```

In other words, display is still displaying?

Because I don`t want the users to close the opened Outlook mail screen.

Comment: I think here you may find the answer. But it also depends on the version of outlook you are using. http://www.slipstick.com/developer/outlook-vba-work-with-open-item-or-select-item/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So essentially you want to find out when the message is closed? Call Display specifying TRUE as the parameter (it defaults to false if not specified) - that will cause Display to be modal. The line `.Display` needs to be changed to `.Display(true)`

Comment: Could you please explain more what you mean? Are you suggesting a code or what?

Comment: Thank you. But, how to find out when the message is closed?

Comment: MailItem.Display(true) will be modal. It will return only when the inspector is closed.